# Show comments in nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget

How do I include the comments that I write above my methods and properties in my nuget package? Ie. So when the library is consumed the user can use intellisense and read what the method is about?

eg. if I have the method

```
/// <summary>
/// This method does such and such
/// </summary>
public void SomeMethod()
{
   // does something..
}
```

Then I want to user to be able to see "This method does such and such" as they type the method.

Comment: Discussion & recommended solution: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795#issuecomment-289782712

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right-click on the project, choose "Properties", then in the Build -> Output section of the Properties page, select the checkbox next to "Documentation file". Leave the file path empty so that it generates the file in the default location, which is where NuGet will expect it to be located.

Alternately, you can add the following to the `.csproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Personally, I always put the above in a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file in the root of the solution so that it's applied to all projects (I also put other common settings there like `<TargetFramework>` etc.).

In previous versions of .NET Core/VisualStudio, a bug caused the checkbox to [store an absolute path](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/319886/default-xml-documentation-file-path-is-absolute.html) to the documentation file which was obviously not ideal for teams. The bug is now be fixed [as of version 16.9](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/368).

Comment: The preview feature was released [in Visual Studio 16.9](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/6746). Now, just check the Build > Output > Documentation file checkbox in the project properties and it will set `GenerateDocumentationFile` appropriately.

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper thanks! I rewrote the answer to reflect the current state of the Visual Studio UI.

Answer (score 20):

You have to enable the XML-Documentation when building.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.100).aspx)

In Project-Properties go to the Build-Tab and select Xml-Documentationfile.

Looks similiar to this

[image: German Version of Visual Studio]